# Getting Magic Number from webm and other files

Tags: java, kotlin

I'm trying to get the magic number of files in kotlin but webm is giving me a hard time.

The magic number is supposed to be `1A 45 DF A3` but I'm getting `1A 45 7E3 FFFD` so it's obvious I'm doing something wrong, HxD Hex Editor does show the correct `1A 45 DF A3` so it's not the files that are wrong.

webm files from https://www.webmfiles.org/demo-files/

```kotlin
#!/usr/bin/env kscript

import java.io.File

val files = arrayListOf<File>()
files.add(File("big-buck-bunny_trailer.webm"))
files.add(File("elephants-dream.webm"))

for (file in files){
  val buffered_reader = file.bufferedReader()
  var first_bytes: String =  ""

  println("-".repeat(20))
  println(file.name)
  println("-".repeat(20))
  for (i in 1..5) {
      try {
          // readbyte
          val a = buffered_reader.read()
          println(a.toString() + "\t" + String.format("%02X ", a) + "\t" + String.format("%02X ", a and 0xFF) + "\t" + a.toChar())
          first_bytes = first_bytes.plus(a)
      } catch (e:java.io.IOException) {
          println("Exception: "+e.localizedMessage)
      }

  }
  buffered_reader.close()
}
```

`kscript main.kts` output

```sh
--------------------
big-buck-bunny_trailer.webm
--------------------
26      1A      1A      
69      45      45      E
2019    7E3     E3      ߣ
65533   FFFD    FD      �
66      42      42      B
--------------------
elephants-dream.webm
--------------------
26      1A      1A      
69      45      45      E
2019    7E3     E3      ߣ
65533   FFFD    FD      �
66      42      42      B
```

### **Edit: the corrected script using InputStream**

```kotlin
#!/usr/bin/env kscript

import java.io.File

val files = arrayListOf<File>()
files.add(File("big-buck-bunny_trailer.webm"))
files.add(File("elephants-dream.webm"))

for (file in files){
  val input_stream = file.inputStream()
  var bytes_read = ByteArray(10)
  var first_bytes: String =  ""
  input_stream.read(bytes_read)

  println("-".repeat(20))
  println(file.name)
  println("-".repeat(20))
  for (byte in bytes_read) {
    try {
        println(byte.toString() + "\t" + String.format("%02X", byte) + "\t" + byte.toChar())
    } catch (e:java.io.IOException) {
        println("Exception: "+e.localizedMessage)
    }
  }
  input_stream.close()
}
```

correct `kscript main.kts` output

```sh
--------------------
big-buck-bunny_trailer.webm
--------------------
26      1A      
69      45      E
-33     DF      ￟
-93     A3      ﾣ
-93     A3      ﾣ
66      42      B
-122    86      ﾆ
-127    81      ﾁ
1       01      
66      42      B
--------------------
elephants-dream.webm
--------------------
26      1A      
69      45      E
-33     DF      ￟
-93     A3      ﾣ
-93     A3      ﾣ
66      42      B
-122    86      ﾆ
-127    81      ﾁ
1       01      
66      42      B
```

### Edit 2: Just a prettier way to print the hex values, for my case this is enough since I'm not comparing many formats, just videos and images.

```kotlin
#!/usr/bin/env kscript

import java.io.File

val files = arrayListOf<File>()
files.add(File("big-buck-bunny_trailer.webm"))
files.add(File("elephants-dream.webm"))

for (file in files){
  val input_stream = file.inputStream()
  var bytes_read = ByteArray(10)
  var first_bytes: String =  ""
  input_stream.read(bytes_read)

  println("-".repeat(20))
  println(file.name)
  println("-".repeat(20))
  first_bytes = bytes_read.joinToString(separator=" ", transform = { byte: Byte -> String.format("%02X",byte) })
  println(first_bytes)
  input_stream.close()
}
```

```
--------------------
big-buck-bunny_trailer.webm
--------------------
1A 45 DF A3 A3 42 86 81 01 42
--------------------
elephants-dream.webm
--------------------
1A 45 DF A3 A3 42 86 81 01 42
```

**This is my end result:**

```kotlin
if (first_bytes.contains("66 74 79 70 69 73") || first_bytes.contains("66 74 79 70 6D 70")) {
        type = "mp4"
    } else if (first_bytes.contains("66 74 79 70 4D 34")) {
        type = "m4v"
    } else if (first_bytes.contains("66 74 79 70 71 74")) {
        type = "mov"
    } else if (first_bytes.startsWith("89 50 4E 47 0D 0A 1A 0A")) {
        type = "png"
    } else if (first_bytes.startsWith("47 49 46 38 3")) {
        type = "gif"
    } else if (first_bytes.startsWith("FF D8 FF")) {
        type = "jpg"
    } else if (first_bytes.startsWith("52 49 46 46") && first_bytes.endsWith("57 45 42 50")) {
        type = "webp"
    } else if (first_bytes.startsWith("1A 45 DF A3")) {
        type = "webm"
    } else {
        type = "unknown"
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use a `BufferedReader`, but an `InputStream`.  `BufferedReader` is for files that consist of text data.

Comment: Mmm.  More specifically, `InputStream`s and `OutputStream`s deal with _bytes_, whereas `Reader`s and `Writer`s deal with _characters_ in some encoding (specified explicitly, or the platform's default, usually UTF-8); and in many encodings, one character is represented by multiple bytes.